# How to share cache between a task and a view with Django?

Tags: python, django, celery

In my django project, I got a task running every 5 minutes (with Celery and Redis as a broker):

```
from django.core.cache import cache

@shared_task()
@celery.task(base=QueueOnce)
def cache_date():
    cache.set('date', datetime.now)
    print('Cached date : ', cache.get('date'))
```

And it's running fine, printing the new cached date everytime it runs

But then, somewhere in one of my views I try to do this :

```
from django.core.cache import cache

def get_cached_date():
    print('Cached date :', cache.get('date')
```

**And then it prints "Cached date : None"**

Here's my cache settings :

```
CACHES = {
   'default': {
      'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
      'LOCATION': '/tmp/cache',
   }
}
```

I don't get it, why is the value available in one place and not in the other while I'm using a singe location file ? Am I trying to do something wrong?

**UPDATE**

@Satevg I use docker-compose, here is my file :

```
services:
  redis:
    image: redis

  worker:
    image: project
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - webserver
    command: project backend worker
    volumes:
    - cache:/tmp/cache

  webserver:
    image: project
    depends_on:
      - redis
    volumes:
      - cache:/tmp/cache

volumes:
  cache:
```

I tried to share the volumes like this, but when my task tries to write to the cache I get :

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/cache/tmpAg_TAc'
```

When I look at the filesystems in both containers I can see the folder /tmp/cache, the web app can even write on it and when I look on the worker's container /tmp/cache folder I can see the updated cache

**UPDATE2:**

The webapp can write to the cache.

```
cache.set('test', 'Test')
```

On the worker's container, I can see the cache file on the /tmp/cache folder
When the task tries to read from cache :

```
print(cache.get('test'))
```

It says :

```
None
```

When the task tries to write from cache it still gets Errno13

Comment: Can you please tell a little bit more. How your application being deployed? Does celery worker and web app working on different instances or docker containers, etc.

Comment: As `FileBasedCache` stores each cache entry in separate files. So check also `/tmp/cache` folder if there are 'cache files'. It seems that celery and app does not share same filesystem.

Comment: You are 100% right, I feel stupid for not thinking about it. I run my webapp and celery worker in 2 different docker containers ... Thanks for the enlightment !
Would you know anyway to share a cache between the two containers?

Comment: Do you use docker-compose to start your services or plain docker command? Share it also please, I'll take a look

Comment: @Satevg I posted my docker-compose file in an update

Comment: So `OSError` happens only when task tries to write cache value? Web app is ok with write operation?

Comment: @Satevg yes exactly, I updated the original post again

Comment: something wrong with permissions... Looks like task is running under different user.  Try to `chmod -R 666 cache/` outside of containers. You should see this folder in your project root directory near compose file.

Comment: I just did this but still get the same error, the directory is located near my docker compose file as you said, webapp still works fine though

Comment: It's hard to say what's going wrong without additional info. See https://medium.com/@nielssj/docker-volumes-and-file-system-permissions-772c1aee23ca I think it would solve your problem. If not, then you're welcome to ask 1 more question here, but with `docker-compose` tag. We're quite far from original problem ;) @OG Django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we figured out in comments, celery and app are working in different docker containers.

`django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache` serializes and stores each cache value as a separate file. But these files are in *different* file systems.

The solution is to use [docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#start-a-service-with-volumes) in order to share `/tmp/cache` folder between these two containers.

Comment: An even better solution would be to use a more appropriate cache backend, such as memcached or redis, that can be shared by multiple services.

Comment: @DanielRoseman yep, OP even has redis in his setup. But he'll need `django-redis-cache` package also. For local development I think it's ok to use filesystem cache. But I wouldn't use it in prod. @OG Django

Comment: @DanielRoseman why would this be better? I'm interested in using redis, any insights on how to configure it with docker-compose ?